# Firebase Security Rules request.auth is null with React Native Firebase v6

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, react-native-firebase

My react native expo managed workflow app is using google sign in with @react-native-firebase and @react-native-google-signin. The user state is authenticated and auth().currentUser is returning the user object correctly.

But my firestore rules are denying the docs retrieval when request.auth != null, and allowing when reques.auth == null.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

React Native code:

```
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({
        showPlayServicesUpdateDialog: true,
      });
      const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
      auth()
        .signInWithCredential(googleCredential)
        .then(async (data) => {
          await setUserInFirestore(data.user);
          const { uid, displayName, email, photoURL } = data.user;
          await AsyncStorage.setItem(
            "user",
            JSON.stringify({ uid, displayName, email, photoURL })
          );
          if (data.user?.metadata) {
            // const date = new Date(user?.metadata?.creationTime);
            const date = data.user.metadata.creationTime.slice(0, 10);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("userDate", date);
            // console.log("\n\n\n", date, "\n\n\n\nsetup done");
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setError(error);
          navigation.navigate(routes.WELCOME);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
      navigation.navigate(routes.WELCOME);
      // // console.log("Error signing in with Google:", error);
    }
  };
```

setUserInFirestore method:

```
const setUserInFirestore = async (user) => {
    const { uid, displayName, email, photoURL } = user;

    try {
      const userRef = doc(db, "users", uid);
      const snapshot = await getDoc(userRef);
      // // console.log("\nUser snapshot inside this method:\n", snapshot);

      if (!snapshot.exists()) {
        await setDoc(userRef, {
          displayName,
          email,
          photoURL,
          uid,
          subscription: null,
          createdAt: new Date(),
        });
        setIsNewUser(true);
        // // console.log("insdie if statement of exisits");
      }
      // console.log("\nUser added to Firestore\n");
      setUser(user);
      setUserContext(user);
    } catch (error) {
      // console.log("\nError adding user to Firestore:\n", error.message);
      setError(error);
    }
  };
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      webClientId: key,
    });

    const unsubscribe = auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe; // Cleanup the subscription on unmount
  }, []);
```

For now to test & debug I'm using simple conditions to atleast make it work.

All the plugins and setup are done correctly according to docs, so what's the solution to this?

Fix(already tried but not worked):

- Updating firebase-tools globally

Versions:

- "firebase": "^9.21.0",
- "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.4.3",
- "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.4.3",

Comment: Please edit the question to show your client app code and how you are verifying that a user is signed in at the time you make the query. Also show how you are handling any errors and the error message itself.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can use to duplicate the behavior as you see it.

Comment: Yes I have added the code snippets